# Handling email attachments through Filesystem, correct or unnecessary?

Tags: magento2, email, file-upload

I have a custom contact form for sending emails. One of the options is to attach a PDF.

This is the part of the controller that handles checking the attachments and uploading them.

```
    $files = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();

        if ($files['attachments'] && $files['attachments']['size'] > 0) {
            if ($files['attachments']['size'] > self::ATTACHMENT_SIZE_LIMIT) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('File size too large.'));
                return $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
            try {
                $uploader = $this->fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'attachments']);
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['pdf']);

            // write to the TMP directory since we don't need the file once it's emailed

                $directory = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::TMP);

                $filePath = $directory->getAbsolutePath('contact-attachments');

                $result = $uploader->save($filePath);
                $resultName = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();

                $attachmentPath = $result['path'] . $result['file'];
                $attachmentName = $resultName;

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('File format not supported.'));
                $this->logger->error($e);
                return $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            }
        } else {
            $attachmentPath = '';
            $attachmentName = '';
        }
```

Is there any benefit to doing this vs. something simple like:

```
$attachmentPath = $files['attachments']['tmp_name'];
$attachmentName = $files['attachments']['name'];
```

With the necessary validations for type and size limit? Am I overthinking this? Both work, I'm just wondering if injecting the Filesystem and Uploader Factory is really necessary.

The transport builder is extended by using the Zend Framework `createAttachment` function, which for whatever reason is not included in Magento 2's base `TransportBuilder`.